# Unable to locate package gitlab-ce on Ubuntu vivid

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I have Ubuntu vivid and I am trying to install Gitlab. I have tried

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=8.5.4-ce.0
```

But I get this error:

```
Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

I can find a repo file, when I do:
    ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d

What can I do to install Gitlab correctly?